# Get the exact raw URL in IIS 7.0 integrated mode ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, url, iis-7

After some changes in `web.config` now IIS allows characters like ":" in URL but it makes some modifications. For example:

```
http://localhost/a///b => http://localhost/a/b (remove all slashes but one)
http://localhost/a\b => http://localhost/a/b (changes backslash with slash)
...
```

I want URL string from within a `HttpHandler` (I use `Request.RawUrl`) as it is without any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the browser is making those changes, not the server. Test it by sending raw request from within code, using AJAX or something like that and see what you get on the server side.